# Java If Statement help for beginner

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm just learning java so this is probaly a really dumb question but i can't find a simple enough answer. I'm trying to make a make the program so if the user types "male" to run the System.out.print("You are a guy");
Here's my code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class clac {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double gender;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Are you male or female? ");
        gender = input.nextDouble();
        if (gender == "male"){
            System.out.println("You are a guy");
        }else{
            System.out.print("You are a gal.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so you are trying to store a string value in a double data type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing wrong: You need to read a String. A String is a piece of text. A double is a decimal number. You are reading a double.

How to solve it:

```
String gender = input.next(); // read a String, instead of double
if (gender.equals("male")) // if (gender == "male") use .equals for strings
{
    System.out.println("U mad bro!?");
} else
{
    System.out.println("Hey Doll!");
}
```

Comment: And use equals() instead of ==

Comment: @Nambari: I was going to add that. But first I start with a very short and quick answer and then immediately start expanding it :)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Sorry i'm do dumb

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `nextDouble()`, that refers to a decimal.

Comment: What varible type should i use then?

Comment: You should probably learn from a textbook, tutorial etc., you're not going to get very far guessing at methods that compile.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  String gender = input.nextString();
    if ("male".equals(gender)){
        System.out.println("Wazzup dude?");
    }else{
        System.out.print("Hey Doll!");
    }
```

Comment: the String var is not being highlighted

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use the **.next()** method for scanner.  Try something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class clac {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Define gender variable as a string since that's what we're expecting as an input
        string gender;
        //Instantiate a Scanner object
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Ask the user a question
        System.out.print("Are you male or female? ");
        //Read in the response into the gender variable
        gender = input.next();
        //Check to see if the user's answer matches "male"
        //We put "male" first in case the user returns a null value
        //This will help avoid a fatal error
        if ("male".equals(gender)){
            System.out.println("You are a guy");
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("You are a gal.");
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the equals method to compare the two strings,the string is a object,this is a reference,the equals() method will compare the content of two strings,but the == will compare the address of two strings

so,you should write like this:

```
gender = input.next();
if (gender.equals("male")){
    System.out.println("You are a guy");
}else{
    System.out.print("You are a gal.");
}
```